# Spring boot 2: Apparent connection leak detected when using Flyway

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I have spring boot 2 app, I am using Flyway for DB migrations. I programmatically execute flyway migration at the app start. When doing that I got: **java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected**

On the row:

```
Database database = org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(flyway, false);
```

Here is my Hikari CP config:

```
spring.datasource.max-active=20
spring.datasource.idle-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.initial-size=20
spring.datasource.test-on-return=true
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=10000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Flyway apparently does not close connections. The solution is to handle that manually:

```
try (Database database = DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(flyway, false)) {
     database.getMainConnection(); // this is important, otherwise there will be connection leak
     doRunMigrations(database);
}
```